# How do you add array in Data portion of Java HTTP POST request?

Tags: java, apache, http-post, multipart

I'm writing an HTTP POST request in Java using Apache `HttpPost` and `MultipartEntity`.  In the data portion of the request, I am able to add simple parts using `addPart(name, StringBody)`.  However, I need to add body part that is an array of values.  How do I do this?  The example from a curl request is:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "name":"someName", 
"email":"noone@nowhere.com", "properties" : { "prop1" : "123", "prop2" : "abc" }}' 
-X POST 'https://some.place.com/api/test'
```

In Java, I can create the request like this, but I need to know how to create the "properties" array value since StringBody is for a single value:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(newAdultUrl);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("someName"));
entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("noone@nowhere.com"));
entity.addPart("properties", new ??? );
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should use a JSON library to do the encoding for you, it's much cleaner and flexible; a simple one is Gson.

Comment: Ok, I have found one approach. I can use a StringEntity instead of a MultipartEntity and create my own JSON string from the various data fields required (we have used both Gson and json-simple in our stack).  However, if someone knows of how to use the MultipartEntity approach from my code sample above I would still prefer that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that works using StringEntity instead of MultipartEntity:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(newUrl);
String jsonData = <create using your favorite JSON library>;
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonData);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

I would like to see an answer using MultipartEntity if there is one, but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

I did a similar thing as Roberg, but for me worked when I added `[]` to the end of the keys, like:

```
 entity.addPart("properties[]", new StringBody("value 1"));
 entity.addPart("properties[]", new StringBody("value 2"));
 entity.addPart("properties[]", new StringBody("value 3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `StringBody` pass a method that converts an array to json.
For example [JSONArray](http://%20Construct%20a%20JSONArray%20from%20a%20Collection.)

```
new JSONArray(collection).toString()
```

Comment: That would pass the array as a String instead of an array.  I need "properties" : {"key":"value"}, not "properties" : "{"key":"value"}".

Comment: try creating an InputStream and use org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody Actually I misunderstood your question and now I am only guessing

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too and was able to figure out the answer.

```
entity.addPart("properties[prop1]", new StringBody("123");
entity.addPart("properties[prop2]", new StringBody("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `properties[]` or `properties` did NOT work for me.

To specify number for each array works fine as below.

```
 entity.addPart("properties[0]", new StringBody("value 1");
 entity.addPart("properties[1]", new StringBody("value 2");
 entity.addPart("properties[2]", new StringBody("value 3");
```